# Search for string and add line in vi/vim

Tags: vim, vi

I'm trying to edit a config file and want to add a specific line of code (on a newline) whenever a specific string is matched...everything I've searched for does search and replace, I'm looking for search and append...

Answer (score 18):

personally, i think using ":g" command is probably better than ":s" for this problem.

```
:g/key/norm owhat ever you want
```

will make text:

```
foo
bar
key
foo2
bar2
key2
blah
```

to:

```
foo
bar
key
what ever you want
foo2
bar2
key2
what ever you want
blah
```

if you want to add the new line above the line containing the pattern, just change the small "o" to "O".

Comment: better than `norm o` is `put ='whatever you want'`

Comment: If you have the `autoindent` option set, `norm o` and `norm O` have the possible advantage that they will use the same indentation as the line you were searching for.

Answer (score 15):

In `vim` `\r` is the new-line. So you can do something like this

```
%s/search string/&\rnew code/
```

Comment: For clarification. When using substitute the ampersand makes it appending? Or does it contain the line you're replacing so you could prepend with "%s/search string/\rnewcode&/"?

Comment: @Jaypal `%s/^.*search string.*$/&\rnew code/` might be better? Yours may break the original line. for example, if the line is "search string=xyz" or "foosearch string=barsearch string"

Comment: `\r` is new line in substitute string. In a search pattern `\n` is new line.

Comment: @VolatileStorm The `&` symbol inserts the search hit

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do:

```
:g/specific string/s/.*/&specific line of code
```

The `g` command fetches all lines containing `specific string` and then apply the `s` substitute command to those lines. The `s` command substitutes the whole line with its contents plus the `specific line of code`

HTH